# PowerShell ran with Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell

I have created a power-shell script that will do the follow: 1. Stop a windows service, wait 60 seconds, Check if the service is still running, if it is send an email and then reboot the server, if it is not running just reboot. The script works fine when ran as administrator but when setup with a scheduled task the script will do everything but reboot the device. I have configured the scheduled task to use -executionpolicy bypass for the argument.

```
    $ServiceName = 'Print Spooler'
    Stop-Service -Name $ServiceName
    sleep -Seconds 60
    function FuncCheckService{
    param($ServiceName)
    $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
      FuncMail -To "to-email" -From "from-email"  -Subject "Servername : 
    ($ServiceName) Failed." -Body "Service $ServiceName Failed to Stop" -
    smtpServer "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        Restart-Computer
    }
    else {
    Restart-Computer
    }
    } 
   function FuncMail {
   #param($strTo, $strFrom, $strSubject, $strBody, $smtpServer)
   param($To, $From, $Subject, $Body, $smtpServer)
   $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
   $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587)
   $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“Username”, 
   “Password”);
   $smtp.EnableSsl = $true
   $msg.From = $From
   $msg.To.Add($To)
   $msg.Subject = $Subject
   $msg.IsBodyHtml = 1
   $msg.Body = $Body
   $smtp.Send($msg)
   } 
   FuncCheckService -ServiceName "Print Spooler"
```

Schedule task run the script and reboot

Schedule task will only stop the windows task and send an email if it is still running after 60 second.

Comment: The argument I am using is "-Executionpolicy bypass -File C:\PScript\stopservice.ps1"

Comment: Try `Restart-Computer -Force`.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you use `FuncMail` and not `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: Is your task set to use highest privileges?

Comment: Yeah, you gotta use the `-Force` param on `Restart-Computer`. Otherwise it will not reboot if anybody is logged on to the machine.